# Apache Axis2 runtime dependency list

Tags: apache-axis, axis

I downloaded the latest axis2 snapshot from [Apache Axis2 repository](http://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/axis2/) however I cannot find the dependency list of jars I need at runtime.  Where can I find the dependency list for this project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will have better luck if you just download builds, they worked for me

[distribution](https://builds.apache.org/job/Axis2/ws/axis2/modules/distribution/target/)

there is a war file for the server installation and there is bin for your ide use